# different Image sizes(resolution) as input for inference on CNN

Tags: neural-network, conv-neural-network

This may be a basic conceptual question, but reading on different CNN's such as VGG, Alexnet, GoogleNet, etc it seems that once the model has been trained on a specific image size as input (lets say 256x256), I can't give a different image size to the model (1,920 x 1,080) during inference without resizing or croping. Is this true?

I know that YOLO handles images with different resolutions, is Yolo resizing the image before giving it to the convolution layers?

The requirement that I have is to do object recognition on a series of images that may not have the same image size, the obvious approach would be resizing the image, but that may lead to losing information on the image.

If so, do I need to train a model for every image size that I have, and then reload the model each time for that specific image?

Comment: You do not need to train the model for every image size. Yolo does resize the input images, but this step is different than cropping the images and doesn't lead to any loss in information. Everything is to scale, so resizing and normalization will not hurt the performance, if not helping it.

Answer (score 1):

There are more conceptual issues, VGG, AlexNet, GoogleNet are image classification models, while YOLO is an object detection model. Only if the network is fully convolutional it can accept variable-sized images.

So your only option is resize images to a common size, this works well in practice, so you should do it and evaluate different image sizes to see how accuracy changes with it. Only after doing such experiment you can decide if resizing is not appropriate.

Comment: Thank you very much, so as I understand I can't have the fully connected layers at the end if I want variable size images. So are there any fully convoluted networks for image classification? I understand that Yolo is an object detection model that is fully convoluted, but doesn't it also do classification for each object?